# Show results of different queries in a single gridview on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I got a 'grid view' and three buttons in my web form. Now when I click 'button1' I want to show the respective result for query1 in 'grid view' and for 'button2' it should show the result of query2. Same for button3.

HTML of my web form :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master Page/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Dashboard.aspx.cs" Inherits="onlineshopping.Master_Page.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="BillingContent">

    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_dsbrdItems" runat="server" Text="Show Items" />
                </td>
                <td style="width:20px"></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_dsbrdShowInvoices" runat="server" Text="Show Invoices" />
                </td>
                <td style="width:20px"></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_dsbrShowUsers" runat="server" Text="Show Users" />
                </td>
                <td style="width:20px"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <table>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gv_dashboard" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I know that I can bind a query result to 'grid view' and I have done that before. But I don't know what to do to achieve this. And I tried something. I knew its stupid & not gonna work. Still I just tried and didn't work as I expected. This is what I tried.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace onlineshopping.Master_Page
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("connectionstring").ToString());
        string sql = "";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        protected void btn_dsbrdItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(con.State==ConnectionState.Closed)
            { con.Open(); }
            sql = "select * from item";
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.Fill(ds);
            gv_dashboard.DataSource = ds;
            gv_dashboard.DataBind();
            con.Close();

        }

        protected void btn_dsbrdShowInvoices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            { con.Open(); }
            sql = "select * from invoice";
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.Fill(ds);
            gv_dashboard.DataSource = ds;
            gv_dashboard.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }

        protected void btn_dsbrShowUsers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            { con.Open(); }
            sql = "select * from tbl_users";
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.Fill(ds);
            gv_dashboard.DataSource = ds;
            gv_dashboard.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[This is my web form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XjqV.jpg)

I am using 'master page' for side 'menu'. If this question is asked before please help me to find that link. I couldn't find.

Comment: `I just tried and didn't work as I expected.` Any error or what?

Comment: Please try AutoGenerateColumns="true"

Comment: All the table structure is different, right? If yes you could make auto generation column true `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`.

Comment: thanks guys..i didnt knew its this simple..I was expecting some big keywords and coding :p...I just made AutoGenerateColumn="true" and its worked..